# What are the external bars for on bank vaults?

Tags: design, door

I refer to the 3 radially spaced bars on this door:-

[image: door1]

and the two horizontal ones on this door:-

[image: door2]

Many (vault) doors have them, but since they're on the outside, what purpose do they serve? It looks like you could just unbolt them with a spanner and some WD40. Is it something to do with alignment?

Comment: they pull the door open and push the door closed

Comment: "you could just unbolt them with a spanner and some WD40" Sure, what about locking nuts on the other side?? Do you really think they  make it so easy?

Answer (score 1):

The big locking pins that those doors have must be aligned precisely with the holes in which they fit, so the pins can be slid into the holes. Precise alignment is accomplished by mechanically pulling the door into its frame so it is firmly seated there before the big pins get extended to lock the door. the mechanical pulling can be accomplished by a cam shaft on the door which engages locking features in the door frame. turning the cam shaft then progressively pulls the door into the frame tighter and tighter.

the mechanisms shown in the photos are the ones used to pull in and pre-seat the door.